# How to trigger Bootstrap fileinput change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using fileinput control managed by [this js](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) in my project. I want to validate if fileinput has file or not. For that, I am trying to trigger change event of fileinput control. But change event is not being triggered. This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7059pk1/). Below is my change event to catch changes done to Fileinput.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '#testImageInput', function () {
          alert($(this).val());
      });
   });
```

Thank you for suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the updated fiddle link check it

https://jsfiddle.net/b7059pk1/2/

```
$('#testImageInput').change(function () {
                alert($(this).val())
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the jQuery version, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("#testImageInput").change(function (){
        alert($(this).val());
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to target element directly instead of whole document.

Updated fiddle --

https://jsfiddle.net/b7059pk1/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#testImageInput").on('change', function () {
                alert($(this).val());
     });
});
```

P.S : I have used jquery 3.2.1 in the updated fiddle